# Rails app works on local server but the most important page won't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, localhost

I have a room reservation project in Rails. I had a problem in one of my pages in which I fixed and pushed the changes. After fixing this problem, my main page, new reservation page, got an error that only occurs on Heroku and not on localhost. (We're sorry, but something went wrong.)

I cannot see the error that it claims I have. In order to resolve this problem, I rolled back Heroku to the state the main page was working while the page I fixed earlier wasn't: The main page was working again. Then, I cloned the git from Heroku into my local machine and re-pushed it without a single change, and yet the error appeared again! I confirmed with Heroku Bash that the files on the server were actually those I pushed.

I would really appreciate for some help!

**The two errors from Heroku's logs:**

```
2014-09-27T21:53:41.455914+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/views/reservations/new.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end
2014-09-27T21:53:41.455712+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/reservations/new.html.erb:28: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input):
```

**app/views/reservations/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary radius">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title text-center" id="reservations_title"><%= t "new_reservation.title" %>:
          <span class="spinner"
                style="display: none; position: relative; top:4px; left:<%= params[:locale]=="en" ? "2px;" : "4px;" %>"
                id="titleSpinner">
          </span>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <%= form_for ([@user, @reservation]), remote: true  do |f| %>
              <%= render(:partial => 'form_datetime', locals: { f: f }) %>
              <%= render(:partial => 'shared/notifications', locals: { f: f }) %>
              <%= render(:partial => 'form_rooms', locals: { f: f }) %>
          <% end %>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'reservations' %>
```

**form_datetime**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  <%= f.label(:res_date, t("new_reservation.date")) %>
  <%= select_tag(:res_date, options_for_select(generate_reservation_dates(5),params[:res_date]),
                 :class => "form-control") %>

  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
  <%= f.label(:res_time, t("new_reservation.time")) %>
  <%= select_tag(:res_time, options_for_select(generate_reservation_time(),params[:res_time]),
                 :class => "form-control",
                 :prompt => t("new_reservation.time_prompt")) %>
</div>
```

**form_rooms**

```
<div id="room_container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag "Show Rooms", :name => "show_rooms", :class => "btn btn-info radius btn-block", :id => "show_rooms" %>
  </div>

  <% if(!params[:res_date].blank? && !params[:res_time].blank?) %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <% rooms_arr = available_rooms_array(params[:res_date],params[:res_time]) %>
        <% if rooms_arr.size == 0 %>
            <div class="alert alert-warning radius">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
              <%= t "new_reservation.no_rooms" %>
            </div>
        <% else %>

            <% rooms_arr.each do |room| %>
                <button value="<%= room.name %>"
                        name="room_name"
                        class="btn btn-primary radius btn-block">
                  <span class="spinner"
                        style="display: none; position: relative; top:5px; left:<%= params[:locale]=="en" ? "8px;" : "11px;" %>"
                        id="buttonSpinner<%= room.name %>">
                  </span>
                  <% if room.contains_grand_piano %>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= room.name %>
                </button>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**notifications**

```
<div class="form-group" id="notifications_container">
  <% if !flash.now.blank? %>
      <% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
          <div class="alert alert-success radius">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
            <%= flash.now[:notice].html_safe %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if !flash[:warning].blank? %>
          <div class="alert alert-warning radius">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
            <%= flash.now[:warning].html_safe %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
      <% if !flash.now[:error].blank? %>
          <div class="alert alert-danger radius">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
            <%= flash.now[:error].html_safe %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I have also tried to make a new Heroku app - the error persists also with this app. How can I figure out why in a certain rollback of Heroku it did work?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your bug has something to do with the way the asset pipeline is processing your Javascript in production mode. I recommend running locally in production to see if you can re-create your problem.

Run something like the following:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
SECRET_KEY_BASE=not_really_random RDS_DB_NAME=myapp_development rails server -e production -p 4000'
```

Then connect to localhost:4000 and see if you've recreated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem!

The problem was with the extra space after form_for:

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @reservation]), remote: true  do |f| %>
```

It was so difficult to find out, especially because it worked on the local server!